# Segmentation Fault printing 2d array in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, multidimensional-array

I am trying to allocate and print a 2d array in C and my methods seem to work but I get a segmentation fault when printing my array. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define WALL 1;
#define EMPTY 0;

int rows;
int columns;

int startRow, startCol;

void getPuzzleParams();
void printMaze();
int solve(char** puzzle, int, int);
void findStartAndEnd(char** puzzle);

main() {
getPuzzleParams();

char **puzzle;
puzzle = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*rows);
int y;
for(y = 0; y < rows;y++)
    puzzle[y] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*columns);

FILE *fptr;
char c;
char file_name[20];
int i,j;

printf("Type in the name of the file containing the Field\n");
scanf("%s",file_name);
fptr=fopen(file_name,"r");
for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
    for (j=0; j<columns; j++){
        c=fgetc(fptr); 
        while ( !((c == '1')||(c =='0')) ) c=fgetc(fptr);
        puzzle[i][j]=c;
    }
fclose(fptr);

for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<columns; j++)  {
        if (j == 0) printf("\n");                
        printf("%c  ",puzzle[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("\n");

printf("print");
//printMaze(puzzle);
printf("find");
findStartAndEnd(puzzle);
printMaze(puzzle);
solve(puzzle, 1, 2);
}

void getPuzzleParams() {
printf("Enter the dimensions of the puzzle which need to be between 5 and 100\n");
printf("Enter the desired number of Rows: ");
scanf("%d", &rows); 
printf("Enter the desired number of Columns: ");
scanf("%d", &columns);
printf("Rows: %d, Columns: %d\n", rows, columns);
if(rows > 100 || rows < 5 || columns > 100 || columns < 5) {
    getPuzzleParams();
}

}

void printMaze(char** puzzle) {
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
    for (j=0; j<columns; j++)  {
        if (j == 0) printf("\n");                
        printf("%c  ",puzzle[i][j]);
    }
printf("\n");
printf("sdfsdF");
}

void findStartAndEnd(char** puzzle) {
int foundEnterence = 0;
int i;
printf("start");
for(i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    printf("top row");
    if(puzzle[0][i]=='0') {
        if(!foundEnterence) {
            foundEnterence = 1;
            startRow = 0;
            startCol = i;
            puzzle[0][i] = 'S';
        } else {
            puzzle[0][i] = 'G';
        }
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    if(puzzle[i][rows]=='0') {
        if(!foundEnterence) {
            foundEnterence = 1;
            startRow = i;
            startCol = rows;
            puzzle[i][rows] = 'S';
        } else {
            puzzle[i][rows] = 'G';
        }
    }
}
for(i = columns; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(puzzle[rows][i]=='0') {
        if(!foundEnterence) {
            foundEnterence = 1;
            startRow = rows;
            startCol = i;
            puzzle[rows][i] = 'S';
        } else {
            puzzle[rows][i] = 'G';
        }
    }
}
for(i = rows; i >= 0; i++) {
    if(puzzle[i][0]=='0') {
        if(!foundEnterence) {
            foundEnterence = 1;
            startRow = i;
            startCol = 0;
            puzzle[i][0] = 'S';
        } else {
            puzzle[i][0] = 'G';
        }
    }
}
}

int solve(char** puzzle, int x, int y) {
printf("%c",puzzle[x][y]);

}
```

It may be a problem with an improper use of malloc, but I've tried a few different initializations with no success.

Edit: The comand line output is:

```
Enter the dimensions of the puzzle which need to be between 5 and 100
Enter the desired number of Rows: 12
Enter the desired number of Columns: 10
Rows: 12, Columns: 10
Type in the name of the file containing the Field
maze.txt

1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  
1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  
1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  
1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  
1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  
1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  
1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  
1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  
1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  
1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `puzzle = (char **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*rows);` umm... `char *` and `int *` are the same size, but it's a tad confusing.

Comment: @chris - Is there a requirement for that - vague feeling the could be different.

Comment: @AdrianCornish, A pointer is a pointer. I doubt there's any differences between the different types of pointers, but you won't get so lucky if it was, say, `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @chris - I am trying to remember if I saw something in the standards about requirements of pointer size - (never seen anything different in RW though)

Comment: changed 'code'(int *) to 'code'(char *) and it didnt change the problem. My array of 0's and 1's prints fine, buts still prints out segmentation fault before continuing to and other method calls

Comment: I can find nothing in C99 or just that nullptr==void* in C++11 - I see no guarantees that pointer to different types must be the same size

Comment: The C standard requires all data pointers to be the same size (but doesn't require function pointers to be the same size as each other or the same size as data pointers).  POSIX requires function pointers to be the same size as data pointers.

Comment: @AdrianCornish, Indeed I see nothing in C11 about it. At jon, could you give a reference if you can find it?

Comment: Apart from the weird (but probably fine) use of `int*` instead of `char*`, your allocation and usage look fine.  If it prints out the array correctly, as you say, then that is not the problem.  You need to show your other functions: `findStartAndEnd` would be a good start.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §6.2.5 Types, ¶28 _A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
pointer to a character type.48) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All
pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same
representation or alignment requirements._

Comment: @paddy The `findStartAndEnd` function never gets called though. The segmentation fault happens when printing the array

Comment: But this *might* be problematic: `scanf("%s",file_name);`...  Is your file name more than 19 characters long?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, No wonder I didn't find it, thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I cannot see something in the legalese of the standard that says `sizeof(int*)==sizeof(mystruct*)` or even `sizeof(int*)==sizeof(float*)`

Comment: @paddy no, the filename is only 8 characters

Comment: sigh. the crash comes after you print the maze in one of your other functions.

Comment: sorry, Im used to java and println debugging. I have posted the rest of the code.

Comment: When you get a segmentation fault, your first reaction should be to run your program in a debugger. It will help you locate where the error is, and also let you examine variables to help you understand what might have caused the error.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: I've quoted what I think is the relevant section of the standard.  I think I have to agree that while it stipulates about the pointers to unions and structs, and about pointer to char and pointer to void, it doesn't stipulate anything about the relative sizes of any those categories.  I don't know of a compiler where there's a difference, but I don't know all about every C compiler.  (One advantage of quoting the standard is that you can interpret it yourself, ignoring my interpretation if it is wrong.)

Comment: @AdrianCornish: The section of [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12) says: §2.12.3 **Pointer Types**
_All function pointer types shall have the same representation as the type pointer to `void`. Conversion of a function pointer to void * shall not alter the representation. A void * value resulting from such a conversion can be converted back to the original function pointer type, using an explicit cast, without loss of information.
**Note:** The ISO C standard does not require this, but it is required for POSIX conformance._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And can you please show me where the question is tagged with POSIX? The OP says it is C - I do not see this in any C standard

Comment: @AdrianCornish: It's not tagged POSIX.  I've given a quote from POSIX to emphasize that POSIX has different (extra) requirements that C does not impose.  I'd make it all an answer except it would be tangential to the question, so it can be left as comments that can be ignored or whatever.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You cite POSIX requirement to me then admit they are not relevant to the question - Simple question are pointer to different types required by the C language standards to be the same size

Comment: @AdrianCornish: I don't have any other answer than 'this is what the two standards (C and POSIX) say'.  I think you may be right that there is no guarantee that, say, an `int *` and a `float *` are the same size.  However, I'd also be very curious to hear about a real machine where they are not.

Comment: This QUESTION(not the answers) Solved my question so thank you.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're crashing in code you haven't pasted. The print completes without error. As you can see, the entire maze has been printed. You aren't seeing `print` or `find` because they're in the output buffer which you haven't flushed -- you're crashing before your code gets a chance to flush it.

Use a good debugger to see where the fault is occurring.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am a java programmer just starting c and I'm used to println debugging. I did not know things could be stuck in the output buffer. This allowed me to find the rest of my mistakes in my other methods.

Comment: @user1676463: If you use `printf("find\n");` with a newline `\n`, then the output buffer will normally be flushed as part of the `printf()` operation.

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably in `findStartAndEnd`, where you have lines like this:

```
if(puzzle[i][rows]=='0') {
```

and

```
if(puzzle[rows][i]=='0') {
```

First of all, the variable `rows` is the number of rows, and as you should know arrays are indexed from `0` to `(size - 1)`, so the indexing should be `rows - 1`. The other thing is that you use `rows` both for the first *and* second dimension, and as one of the dimensions is only 10 while the other is 12, you go beyond the limits of the memory allocated.